# how do I turn a glass door into a removable mirror?

Tags: windows

A glass door allows outside people to see into a private area. How can the glass door be temporarily converted into a mirror? I am imagining some kind of roll on mylar. But it would need to be removable so that the door could later be converted back into transparent glass without any lingering residue. Can someone please explain how to do this in a way that is explicit enough for a reader to be able to find _and order materials with the right key words?

Comment: Search *mirror film*. There are adhesive plastic films that re removable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically (without getting into product recommendations), look for "static cling film" as opposed to an adhesive product. You can get both mirrored and "stained glass" versions - they apply with water and a squeegee, and peel off again without a fight or residue.

"Privacy film" is another search term; or "window privacy film."

The stained glass or prismatic styles will permit more light to pass while still blocking the view.

Mirrored film can have the effect of putting the "private space" on display at night when the inside is lit and the outside is dark.

Comment: He could use both -- frosted or prismatic privacy film on one side of the glass, mirrored film on the other side (I'm not sure that stacking two layers on one side of the glass would work well). That will give him the mirrored look he desires without also putting himself on display at night. I haven't seen 100% mirrored film that prevents all light from coming through, otherwise that would meet all of this needs.